# c++ (OpenBSD 5.8 amd64), outputting uint64_t as a real number

Tags: c++, char, unions, uint, uint64

Trying to understand why I get the following output from my program:

```
$ ./chartouintest 
UInts: 153 97 67 49 139 0 3 129 
Hexes: 99 61 43 31 8b 00 03 81 
uint64 val: 8103008b31436199
$
```

I am trying to output just the actual UInt64 numerical value, but can't seem to do it (the output is not right)

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

union bytes {
    unsigned char c[8];
    uint64_t l;
} memobj;

int main() {
    //fill with random bytes
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < sizeof(memobj.c); ++i) { memobj.c[i] = (unsigned char)rand();}
    //see values of all elements as unsigned int8's and hex vals
    std::cout << "UInts: ";
    for (int x=0; x < sizeof(memobj.c); ++x) { std::cout << (unsigned int)memobj.c[x] << " "; }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hexes: ";
    for (int x=0; x < sizeof(memobj.c); ++x) { std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << (unsigned int)memobj.c[x] << " "; }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uint64 val: " << memobj.l << std::endl;
}
```

what am i doing wrong???
thanks in advance for the help!

J

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Using both members of the union is UB in C++ by the way.

Comment: While this is undefined behavior, many compilers will follow similar rules on the same architecture. To understand what's going on, try setting one byte to a value and check the result and then go to multiple bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Writing one member of a union and reading another is *undefined behavior* (with exceptions, but in this case it's UB).

You shouldn't *expect* anything. The compiler can do WTF it wants with your code, for instance giving a nice "expected" result in debug mode and garbage or crashing in release mode. Of course another compiler might play another trick. You'll never know for sure, so why bother ?

Why not doing it the right way ? `memcpy` perhaps ?

EDIT:

To **really** answer the question, a note about `std::cout` : the `std::hex` sets the stream to an hexadecimal representation, that's why the final "uint64 val: " display is in hex base (and not in decimal as the OP expects). Other than that, nothing is wrong with the output, despite the UB threat.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, i thought i was doing it the right way :)
Working on memcpy code and will update post , thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @nethereal yes, don't mess with the C++ standards police :-) That said, your output seems quite sane, what is wrong in your opinion ?

Comment: I'm looking for a real number, whereas the output of the uint64 contains what i assume to be some hex characters...

Comment: By "real number" do you mean "integer displayed in a decimal base" ?